# Magento index.php required with SSL for login and checkout pages [HTTP 404]

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, ssl

I am using magento 1.9, I've got installed SSL which is working just fine.

The problem is when I am switching my secure link to https:// - all pages are working correctly, but pages such as checkout, register and login are throwing error 404, unless I manually add prefix with index.php

These links are working correctly when I am working with non-secure connections.

For example this links are working correctly:

1. http://myshop.com/customer/account/login/
2. http://myshop.com/customer/account/create/

But my links

1. https://myshop.com/customer/account/login/
2. https://myshop.com/customer/account/create/

are throwing HTTP 404 - Not Found - In order to make it work I have to manually add `index.php` prefix so my links look like this:

1. http://myshop.com/index.php/customer/account/login/
2. http://myshop.com/index.php/customer/account/create/

I have changed my .htaccess file, and I think the problem lies in this file. How can I edit this file so it fits my purposes ?

Any other solutions are more then welcome also.

Comment: 1: you shouldn't need to edit the root .htaccess file (in fact doing so can break the patching process oddly); 2: check the URLs in config > general > web > secure (they should begin with `https://` if nothing else; none of the "sensitive" pages should be available under http).

Comment: Yes it begins with https:// but I do not want to use index.php anywhere throughout my shop;  So I had to edit my .htaccess file in order to make a rewrite of all pages including index.php to remove it

Comment: You don't need to edit your .htaccess for that though, just go into *config > general > web > Search Engine Optimization* and set *Use Web Server Rewrites* to yes.

Comment: It is already done. But I get HTTP 404 whenever I try to use secure address at login or checkout page

Comment: Set *Use Secure URLs in Frontend* to *yes* ? ... and everything done at Store Level config rather than default?

Comment: Yes I have set this to Yes as well. Yes also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL has its own configuration files and sometimes when SSL does not work well, it may give the error of 404 (Page not found). Normally, the file name  is  http.conf or  ssl.conf or default-ssl file which depends on your OS

Find here:

```
<Directory "path to your directory">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

make sure that AllowOverride All is present in your config

if it does not help attach what OS and web server you are using

Comment: Thanks ! I did not do this inside my http.conf or ssl.conf but this gave me an idea where to look. I have changed my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my-site-ssl.conf` I've added your suggestion and it works great now.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you have enabled  Web Server Rewrites

config > general > web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites > Yes

P.S restore the .htaccess file before try above method

Comment: Please do not include signatures in your posts, as they may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [How not to be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_.  Your usercard is placed at the bottom of every post; you can put whatever you like in your profile!

Comment: I've restored to default .htaccess file, also my User Web Server Rewrites was set to Yes all the time. And still, there is HTTP 404 whenever I try to use secure address at login or checkout page

Answer (score -1):

Checked some of your website current pages such as https://www.myshop.com/registreren and it is working fine with https.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he was using *myshop.com* as an example domain; that actual site's not running on Magento.

Comment: its only an example